# Linq query help

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have two collections, and need to create a new collection from the two collections.

Assume the following class:

```
public class Widget
{
   property int Id{get;set;}
   property string Label{get;set;}
}
```

We have two IList classes. I would like to create an Anonymous type with Id, Label, and Exists

So doing this for Id and Label, I have:

```
var newCol=from w in widgets
           select new {Id=w.Id,Label=w.Label,Exists=????}
```

Is there a way in Linq I can determine exists without writing the looping code myself here?

**Edit**

Exists tells us if the Widget is in the second list. So for example one solution I just thought of was:

```
var newCol=from w in widgets
           select new {Id=w.Id,Label=w.Label,Exists=myWidgets.Contains(w)}
```

Where my widgets is the second IList.

Comment: We need more information. What is the other IList? What does Exists mean? Do you mean you want to check if this widget exists in the other IList?

Comment: Yes so we are basically doing a left join btw two lists, and I want to know when the item is in both lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this using [GroupJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin.aspx):

```
var newCol = widgets.GroupJoin(
    otherWidgets,
    w => w.Id,
    w => w.Id,
    (w, joined) => new { Id = w.Id, Label = w.Label, Exists = joined.Any() });
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is really vague, but I'm guessing this is what you want:

```
var newCol = from w in widgets
             select new { Id = w.Id, Label = w.Label, 
                 Exists = others.Contains(o => o.Id == w.Id }
```

Comment: Yea I'm sorry about the vagueness was having a hard time being explicit.

Comment: beat me to it.  I had to try pretty hard to understand what he was asking.  Though I wouldn't bother with the Lambda in the contains method, just do `Contains(w)`

Comment: @Scott I considered that, but I think it would depend on the Equals and CompareTo methods of his Widget class, which might not work the way he expects if he hasn't overridden/implemented them and if the two collections aren't references to the same object in memory. This way should work regardless.